# washer won't go into the rinse cycle, just hums

Tags: washing-machine, washer

My Whirlpool top load agitator washer is filling, draining and spinning just fine in the wash cycle, but when it hits the rinse cycle, it stops and makes a humming sound.  If I lift the lid the sound stops.

Comment: Providing the model number would be helpful

Comment: If you repeat the washing process again then it stops at the rinse cycle, you might need a new control board. Call Whirlpool with the model/serial number ready and arrange an inspection. It's not likely someone can fix it online.